# How to download streamed and buffered video?

Tags: video, stream

I have video buffered from livestream.com on firefox, however broadcasting has ended few hours ago but I can still go to any time in video and play it back. I'm trying to find a way to save it but If i refresh the page or restart firefox it will be gone for good. Do you have any ideas how to get it? Where can it be cached, this video is 6 hours of full HD so file must be huge and my FF cache is relatively tiny, like few hundred mbs.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the behaviour you are seeing is actually the server re-streaming the video from a particular point when you click the timeline.

In other words the video is not stored on your PC, instead you are actually sending a new request to the server asking it to start re-streaming from the point you move to in the timeline.

In general, a browser will not store a streamed video after it is played by default (or even part of the video after it has played that part) - videos are very large as you note so this would not be practical.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little involved, but there is a description of how to download the video here: http://dgopstein.github.io/articles/downloading-livestream-streaming-video/

Livestream uses M3U playlists to sequence other M3U playlists which list small chunks of MPEG-2 Transport Stream video files.

By downloading the M3U files, and then subsequently the video files, you can merge the files and store and view them locally on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

In the M3U playlist, look for progressive URL. This will contain the complete video file.

`"progressive_url":"http://abc.new.livestream.com/events/0000000090006c9090/3582049f-1d25-48f3-b902-79b4cbe20bc1_897.mp4?end=2090&__gda__=14898312816_9657a3b2e3f4791f3d5f15786380f378","smil_url":....`